# WIX Burn Bootstrapper, installing .net framework as payload

Tags: wix, bundle, bootstrapper, burn, .net-4.8

What I want to do:

Make a wix burn bundle bootstrapper that 1st installs the .net 4.8 framework if necessary and then after that, install our custom MSI
the custom MSI is all good and working.

I want a single file, which I understand will be 100,000 K big and we're fine with that (once you package in the .net 4.8 installer)

Then just have the bootstrapper auto unpackage and run the .net framework install if needed, but everything I've tried doesn't work.  Either it wants to download it (we don't want to count on internet access), or a Open File Dialog shows wanting to get pointed to the .net framework install.

all code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Wix
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Bundle
        Name="OurSoftwareName"
        Version="1.0.0.0"
        Manufacturer="Our Company name"
        UpgradeCode="deleted guid here so no one accidentally uses it">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef
            Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
<!--
        <PayloadGroup Id="NetFx48RedistPayload">
            <Payload Name="redist\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe"
                SourceFile=".\Files\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe"/>
        </PayloadGroup>
-->
        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef
                Id="NetFx48RedistPayload" />
            <MsiPackage
                After="NetFx48Redist"
                SourceFile="$(var.ReferenceToOurMsi.Setup.TargetPath)" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

And I've copied and altered the .net 4.8 version of wix code from and made some customizations:

https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx48.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!-- Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved. Licensed under the Microsoft Reciprocal License. See LICENSE.TXT file in the project root for full license information. -->

<!--
copied from:
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx48.wxs
-->

<Wix
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <!--
        .NET Framework installation state properties

        Official documentation can be found at the following location:

           .NET Framework 4.5.x/4.6.x/4.7.x/4.8.x - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2(v=vs.110).aspx
    -->

    <?define NetFx48MinRelease = 528040 ?>
    <?define NetFx48WebLink = https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2085155 ?>
    <?define NetFx48RedistLink = https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2088631 ?>
    <?define NetFx48EulaLink = https://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html ?>

    <Fragment>
        <PropertyRef
            Id="WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED" />
        <Property
            Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_48_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"
            Secure="yes" />
        <SetProperty
            Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_48_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"
            Value="1"
            After="AppSearch">
            WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED >= "#$(var.NetFx48MinRelease)"
        </SetProperty>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <util:RegistrySearchRef
            Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />

        <WixVariable
            Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId"
            Value="NetFx48Web" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl"
            Value="$(var.NetFx48EulaLink)"
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48WebDetectCondition"
            Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx48MinRelease)"
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48WebInstallCondition"
            Value=""
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48WebPackageDirectory"
            Value="redist\"
            Overridable="yes" />

        <PackageGroup
            Id="NetFx48Web">
            <ExePackage
                InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48WebLog].html&quot;"
                RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48WebLog].html&quot;"
                UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48WebLog].html&quot;"
                PerMachine="yes"
                DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx48WebDetectCondition)"
                InstallCondition="!(wix.NetFx48WebInstallCondition)"
                Id="NetFx48Web"
                Vital="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Protocol="netfx4"
                DownloadUrl="$(var.NetFx48WebLink)"
                LogPathVariable="NetFx48WebLog"
                Compressed="no"
                Name="!(wix.NetFx48WebPackageDirectory)ndp48-web.exe">
                <RemotePayload
                    CertificatePublicKey="F49F9B33E25E33CCA0BFB15A62B7C29FFAB3880B"
                    CertificateThumbprint="ABDCA79AF9DD48A0EA702AD45260B3C03093FB4B"
                    Description="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 Setup"
                    Hash="4181398AA1FD5190155AC3A388434E5F7EA0B667"
                    ProductName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8"
                    Size="1439328"
                    Version="4.8.4115.0" />
            </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <util:RegistrySearchRef
            Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />

        <WixVariable
            Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId"
            Value="NetFx48Redist" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl"
            Value="$(var.NetFx48EulaLink)"
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistDetectCondition"
            Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx48MinRelease)"
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistInstallCondition"
            Value=""
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistPackageDirectory"
            Value="redist\"
            Overridable="yes" />

        <PackageGroup
            Id="NetFx48Redist">
            <ExePackage
                InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                PerMachine="yes"
                DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx48RedistDetectCondition)"
                InstallCondition="!(wix.NetFx48RedistInstallCondition)"
                Id="NetFx48Redist"
                Vital="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Protocol="netfx4"
                DownloadUrl="$(var.NetFx48RedistLink)"
                LogPathVariable="NetFx48RedistLog"
                Compressed="no"
                Name="!(wix.NetFx48RedistPackageDirectory)ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe">
                <RemotePayload
                    CertificatePublicKey="F49F9B33E25E33CCA0BFB15A62B7C29FFAB3880B"
                    CertificateThumbprint="ABDCA79AF9DD48A0EA702AD45260B3C03093FB4B"
                    Description="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 Setup"
                    Hash="E322E2E0FB4C86172C38A97DC6C71982134F0570"
                    ProductName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8"
                    Size="117380440"
                    Version="4.8.4115.0" />
            </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <util:RegistrySearchRef
            Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />

        <WixVariable
            Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId"
            Value="NetFx48Redist" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl"
            Value="$(var.NetFx48EulaLink)"
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistDetectCondition"
            Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx48MinRelease)"
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistInstallCondition"
            Value=""
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistPackageDirectory"
            Value="redist\"
            Overridable="yes" />

        <PackageGroup
            Id="NetFx48RedistPayload">
            <ExePackage
                InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                PerMachine="yes"
                DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx48RedistDetectCondition)"
                InstallCondition="!(wix.NetFx48RedistInstallCondition)"
                Id="NetFx48Redist"
                Vital="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Protocol="netfx4"
                LogPathVariable="NetFx48RedistLog"
                Compressed="no"
                SourceFile=".\Files\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe">

                <Payload Name="ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe"
                    SourceFile=".\Files\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe"/>
            </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: If you don't want .NET to be downloaded I think you need to change the DownloadUrl attribute to SourceFile so that you're actually packaging the full redist.

Comment: tried that with my custom version called "NetFx48RedistPayload" and that didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never found this this on any google hunts, but apparently setting the compressed to "yes" was the key, and no need for a payload when doing that. Worked exactly as I want at this point.  Single (large) file and auto-extracts and runs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!-- Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved. Licensed under the Microsoft Reciprocal License. See LICENSE.TXT file in the project root for full license information. -->

<!--
copied from:
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx48.wxs
-->

<Wix
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <!--
        .NET Framework installation state properties

        Official documentation can be found at the following location:

           .NET Framework 4.5.x/4.6.x/4.7.x/4.8.x - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2(v=vs.110).aspx
    -->

    <?define NetFx48MinRelease = 528040 ?>
    <?define NetFx48WebLink = https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2085155 ?>
    <?define NetFx48RedistLink = https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2088631 ?>
    <?define NetFx48EulaLink = https://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html ?>

    <Fragment>
        <PropertyRef
            Id="WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED" />
        <Property
            Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_48_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"
            Secure="yes" />
        <SetProperty
            Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_48_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"
            Value="1"
            After="AppSearch">
            WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED >= "#$(var.NetFx48MinRelease)"
        </SetProperty>
    </Fragment>

<!-- removed other fragments because they didn't matter -->

    <Fragment>
        <util:RegistrySearchRef
            Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />

        <WixVariable
            Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId"
            Value="NetFx48Redist" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl"
            Value="$(var.NetFx48EulaLink)"
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistDetectCondition"
            Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx48MinRelease)"
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistInstallCondition"
            Value=""
            Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable
            Id="NetFx48RedistPackageDirectory"
            Value="redist\"
            Overridable="yes" />

        <PackageGroup
            Id="NetFx48RedistPayload">
            <ExePackage
                InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx48RedistLog].html&quot;"
                PerMachine="yes"
                DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx48RedistDetectCondition)"
                InstallCondition="!(wix.NetFx48RedistInstallCondition)"
                Id="NetFx48Redist"
                Vital="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Protocol="netfx4"
                LogPathVariable="NetFx48RedistLog"
                Compressed="yes"
                SourceFile=".\Files\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe" />
              
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: It isn't related with some payload element at all...